# video.js: autoclick on play button (to get around iOS autoplay limitation)

Tags: ios, click, html5-video, video.js

I want to have a video.js element autoplay on page load.
This obviously works fine in any (computer) webbrowser with the 'autoplay: true' setting.

But on iOS the autoplay features are globally disabled by apple itself.

I am trying to work around this by having the browser automaticly click the play button when the page is loaded.
But every autoclick solution I found on here did not work. neither on a computer nor in iOS.

is there any way to have an autoclick on a video.js element?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no. Apple has blocked every possibility of doing this that I'm aware of. It's meant to protect iPhone users with expensive mobile data plans from downloading video data that they didn't intend to. It would be nice if autoplay could still work when the user was on wifi, or even if there was a user setting to allow autoplay, but there's nothing like that yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do that. The whole idea of not supporting autoplay is to save battery and bandwidth for mobile users. If this is allowed every page will include video ads in there page and will start playing.

On the other hand you can use one click to do anything else. Something like a welcome page and click you can make the video start.